# How to adapt flatbuffers `table` to be used with `Cow` in `Rust`?

Tags: rust, flatbuffers

I have some hierarchy of traits and i need to adapt both structs and flatbuffers table to be used via the trait as follows:

```
// trait
pub trait TFilter : Clone {
    fn get_text(&self) -> &str;
}

// structure

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct FilterStruct {
    pub text: String
}

impl TFilter for FilterStruct {
    fn get_text(&self) -> &str {
        &self.text
    }
}

impl TFilter for FilterTable<'_> {
    fn get_text(&self) -> &str {
        self.text()
    }
}
```

flatbuffers schema (IDL):

```
table FilterTable {
    text: string (required);
}
```

It works fine with the following usage:

```
pub fn accept_filter(filter: &dyn TFilter) {
    println!("{}", filter.get_text());
}

    accept_filter(&FilterStruct {
        text: "hello".to_owned()
    });
```

The problem happens when i inheritance is introduced:
a new trait that extends the base trait:

```
pub trait TActiveFilter {
    fn get_filter(&self) -> Cow<dyn TFilter>;
    fn get_title(&self) -> &str;
}
```

a new structure that extends the base struct ("extend by containing"):

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct ActiveFilterStruct {
    pub filter: FilterStruct,
    pub title: String
}

impl TActiveFilter for ActiveFilterStruct {
    fn get_filter(&self) -> Cow<dyn TFilter> {
        Cow::Borrowed(&self.filter)
    }
    fn get_title(&self) -> &str {
        &self.title
    }
}
```

and a new flatbuffers table that extends the base table:

```
table ActiveFilterTable {
    filter: FilterTable (required);
    title: string (required);
}
```

```
impl TActiveFilter for ActiveFilterTable<'_> {
    fn get_filter(&self) -> Cow<dyn TFilter> {
        Cow::Owned(self.filter())
    }

    fn get_title(&self) -> &str {
        self.title()
    }
}
```

The actual problem is that flatbuffer's generated Rust file returns instances (not references) and one has to own it, so using the `Cow` (struct already own and returns the reference but flatbuffer's impl has to own the result).

However with Cow i get the following:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `TFilter` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/wrapper.rs:76:30
   |
76 | pub fn accept_filter(filter: Cow<dyn TFilter>) {
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `TFilter` cannot be made into an object
   |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
  --> src/wrapper.rs:5:21
   |
5  | pub trait TFilter : Clone {
   |           -------   ^^^^^ ...because it requires `Self: Sized`
   |           |
   |           this trait cannot be made into an object...
```

What exactly must be made?

Answer (score 0):

Trait objects can not be cloned since their size is unknown. If you take a look at `Clone` and `fn clone(&self) -> Self` you will see that it returns `Self`, in this case `dyn TFilter`. `Cow<T>` requires the `Clone` bound on `T`, otherwise it wouldn't be possible to get an owned instance of `T`.

It's the same error that you will get when trying to pass a raw trait object to a function, e.g.:

```
trait Foo {}
fn foo(_ :dyn Foo) {

}
```

You might be able to work around this by returning `Box<dyn TFilter>` from your `get_filter` method, rather than the `Cow`. Following another approach, you could try to stick to static dispatch rather than trait objects in the `Cow`.

Comment: `Box` takes ownership and it will not work with struct-based impl as it's struct who owns it's field. Correct me. Yup: `impl TActiveFilter for ActiveFilterStruct {
    fn get_filter(&self) -> Box<dyn TFilter> {
        Box::new(self.filter)
    }
    ...
}` - can't move

Comment: You could pass a reference to the `Box`, as long as the reference also implements your trait, it should work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a94e9245357d445d9abcae96ba863b05

The downside is that it introduces a lifetime, otherwise it won't work. But the same holds for the `Cow<'a, B>`.

Comment: @sebpuetx Not sure i understand. In order to pass a reference you have to create a Box that will take the ownership. And this is impossible as 1) if you create a box inside of func you will pass a reference to temporarily instance 2) the struct owns the field. Copy is not implemented and undesired. Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=51d1831991f8c7c8c9b59601b452f750

Comment: You can put a reference into the box: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1298e8488320cb1fbd202680cc07918a As mentioned before, this adds a lifetime parameter on the trait and you'll need to implement the trait for references, too.

It might not be a suitable solution for your problem, but I'm missing context to give a more thorough suggestion.